# Pivot header-like Control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

Is it any separated Control for create something like Pivot header?

I need horizontal list on top of page, binded to my Collection with same behavior like Pivot header - left-right drags(can be done with GestureListener, i think) and with event for select new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a horizontal `ListBox` using the following XAML:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Your control... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```